# System.Net.WebException: 'Anulada la solicitud: No se puede crear un canal seguro SSL/TLS.'

Tags: c#

Trato de consumir una API, cuando recibo la siguiente excepción, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo? Este es mi código:

```
private void consumirAPI()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.host.com/api");

        var postData = "key=512348132487ewjvsdisiw93oopasdi7";

     
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        

        WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        textBox1.Text = responseString.ToString();
    }
```

He probado a indicarle el protocolo ssl y tls mediante:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

y

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Pero no me reconoce:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Me indica que SecurityProtocolType no tiene una definición para 'tls12'

He probado también según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca5386) el método:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 3072;    // TLS 1.2
```

Pero recibo la misma excepción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente el error estaba en la url al quitar www funcionó. Al subir el proyecto a .NET 4.5  ya me reconoció:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Este es el código final:

```
private void consumirAPI()
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://host.com/api");

    var postData = "key=512348132487ewjvsdisiw93oopasdi7";

 
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    

    WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    textBox1.Text = responseString.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En otros casos, asegurate en el archivo host tener la ip y el nombre el sitio, ya que posiblemente intenta resolver localmente. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts